# Where can I find black cocoa powder (a.k.a. black onyx cocoa powder) in the UK?

Tags: shopping, cocoa

I live in the UK and want to buy some black cocoa powder, also known as black onyx cocoa powder. This is a type of cocoa powder that has been alkalized more than standard cocoa powder. As a result, it is much darker than normal cocoa powder and tastes different. It is what is used to make Oreo cookies.

The only places I can find that sell it are in the USA, and they won't ship internationally.

Is it available in the UK? Surely it must be?

Comment: What is so special about this kind (brand?) of cocoa powder?

Comment: @Stephie - It looks like its been more alkalized than typical dutch processed cocoa.

Comment: @Stephie - It's a type of cocoa powder, not a brand; and it's different from normal cocoa powder. I've edited the question to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prevosly purchaced this via a uk retailer on Amazon

But currently out of stock.

I am aware that these guys

http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/spices/cocoa-black-onyx.html

Sell internationally, but you have to phone to order, not place the sale online.  I guess so they can get the shipping right.  But to stress I've never used them